# SpringMVC @Valid in controller method doesnt work

Tags: java, hibernate, validation, spring-portlet-mvc

I have a question. It's my first time, when Im using SpringMVC with Hibernate Validator, and I got a problem.

I have a plain form, for registering Item. So I have Dto:

```
@Data
public class EquipmentDto {

    private Long id;

    @Size(min=2)
    private String code;

    @Size(min=4)
    private String name;

    @NotNull
    private String description;
}
```

And method in controller in Liferay:

```
    @ActionMapping("saveEquipment")
    public void saveEquipment(@Valid @ModelAttribute("dto") EquipmentDto dto, BindingResult result){

        if (result.hasErrors()){
            log.info("save Equipment error");
        }
        else {
            log.info("save Equipment");
            //equipmentService.saveEquipment(dto); Until validation wont work
        }
    }
```

Unfortunatelly, even if code and name fields are empty, validator doesn't see errord, and my EquipmentDto pass to service method. How to fix that? 
Maybe I forgot about configuration?

I have Hibernate validator and validation api on my classpath.

Any ideas guys?

Comment: Seems like https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-9560

Comment: do you have `<mvc:annotation-driven />` in your application context ?

Comment: could you try to remove Data annotation and use Getters/Setters? i know is the same, but just because few days ago i read the Data sometimes was not working properly